# R Object not found error when using tidy evaluation and group by in function

Tags: r

I am writing a function that should return a pieplot. Now I don't understand why it does not find the grouping variable. Every time I run this, it throws an error: `Error in as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE): object 't1gender' not found`. `t1gender` is the variable I want to group by.

The thing is, I cannot just use the variable in a function as I would usually with `group_by()`. See here: [dcl-prog.stanford.edu/tidy-eval-basics.html](https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/tidy-eval-basics.html). I want `varname` to behave as a hybrid between an environment variable and a data variable. Like an environment variable, I want it to refer to another value (`t1gender`). Then, I want `group_by()` to treat that value (`t1gender`) as a data variable and look inside `data` for the matching column.

Any hints are very welcome!

Here is my reprex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(
  ID_code = c(1001L,1002L,1003L,
              1004L,1005L,1006L,1007L,1008L,1009L,1010L),
  t1gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)
)

pie_plot <- function(data = data, labels, varname, colors) {
  lbls <- labels
  count <- data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{varname}}) %>% 
    tally() %>%
    .[2] %>%
    .[1:length(labels), ] %>%
    unlist(.)
  df <- as_tibble(cbind(count, lbls))
  plot_ly(df, labels = ~lbls, values = ~count,
          marker = list(colors = colors,
                        line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
          type = "pie", width = 280, height = 280)
}

pie_plot(data, labels = c("Male", "Female"), varname = t1gender, colors = c('#440154FF', '#21908CFF'))
#> Error in as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE): object 't1gender' not found
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it :)

```
pie_plot <- function(data, labels, varname, colors) {
  lbls <- labels
  count <- data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{varname}}) %>% 
    tally() %>%
    .[2] %>%
    .[1:length(labels), ] %>%
    unlist(.)
  df <- as_tibble(cbind(count, lbls))
  plot_ly(df, labels = df$lbls, values = df$count,
         marker = list(colors = colors,
                       line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
         type = "pie", width = 280, height = 280)
}

pie_plot(data, labels = c("Male", "Female"), varname = t1gender, colors = c('#440154FF', '#21908CFF'))
```

Comment: That does also not work. It then gives me a plot with 100% male (so it does not find the  1s and 2s in the t1gender column.

Comment: The thing is, I cannot just use the variable in a function as I would usually with ```group_by```. See here: https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/tidy-eval-basics.html. I want ```varname``` to behave as a hybrid between an environment variable and a data variable. Like an environment variable, I want it to refer to another value (```t1gender```). Then, I want ```group_by()``` to treat that value (```t1gender```) as a data variable and look inside ```data``` for the matching column.

Comment: Please check updated answer. Looks like labels and values have to be called as `df$...`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! Yes, of course, it did not find ```t1gender``` in the ```plot_ly()``` call and not above, duh. :)